# jQuery .submit() not triggering

Tags: jquery, html, submit

I've done a lot of searching but can't find out why my jQuery `.submit()` will not trigger. I've also tried with `.click()` for the submit button.

I've currently got a div template (includes a form):

```
<div class="reply-to-existing-message" style="display: none">
        <form class="reply-message-form">
            <textarea id="post-reply-message-textarea" name="PostReplyMessage[message]" rows="3" cols="40" style="resize: none"></textarea>
            <input class="reply-to-message-id" type="hidden" name="PostReplyMessage[id]" />
            <input class="post-reply-message-submit" type="submit" value="Reply"/>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I append this to a message using jQuery when the reply button is clicked (produces a drop down reply form so user can reply to a message). This works fine (double checked using firebug too).

However, my jQuery code doesn't produce the alert when I click on the submit button, so it's not even triggering. Could someone please explain why this is occurring, thanks! jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.reply-message-form').submit(function() {
        alert('test');
        return false;
    }) ;
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're dynamically adding content, that static call to `.submit()` isn't going to work for you. That will only bind the event handler to the elements that matched the selector *at the time it was run*, so any elements added after that won't have the event handler bound.

The solution is **event delegation**, using the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.reply-message-form', function(e) {
    alert('test');
    return false;
});
```

Ideally, rather than using `document`, you'd select the closest static (i.e. exists when the page loads) element that will contain all of your dynamic content.

Alternatively, if you're using a version of jQuery prior to 1.7 and therefore don't have access to the `.on()` function, you can use the [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) function instead:

```
$(document).delegate('.reply-message-form', 'submit', function(e) {
    alert('test');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Fantastic - thought the dynamic generation might have had a role to play. Thanks for your quick answer :)

Comment: @cud_programmer No problem at all!

Comment: This saved my whole afternoon after 2 hours of solution searching!

Answer (score 3):

For dynamically generated elements, you should delegate the events, you can use the `on` method, try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'input[type=submit]', function() {
        alert('test');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Fantastic - thought the dynamic generation might have had a role to play. Thanks for your quick answer :)